# CSS display destroys shadow :after and :before

Tags: html, css

I'm showing a box-shadow at the bottom of my navigation:
http://jsfiddle.net/A6xYV/

```
nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
}
nav:before, nav:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width:300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
nav:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM - IT SHOULD BE INLINE!
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CDCDCC;
}
```

This works perfect. But I want my navigation elements to be display: inline;
http://jsfiddle.net/gWafk/

Why does it not work?

Comment: Your shadow needs a height of 120px or so to be displayed. That's why it doesn't show in your second example.

Comment: @vals How can I reduce the minimum height?

Comment: @zerophreak look into `min-height` and `max-height` properties.

Comment: No way to make it fluid? In case the height changes?

Comment: Not to hijack, but see solution below for "fluid heights" friendly approach

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. The issue was basically setting `top` in terms of relative height. You can see the issue if you remove one `<li>` at a time, seeing what happens to the shadow every time. I also made the backgrounds of those shadow-producing divs transparent so it works at many different heights.

UPDATE for smaller widths to 320px: http://jsfiddle.net/iamnotsam/gWafk/8/

Comment: I don't see any changes on this fiddle.. :(

Comment: Also, keeping the basic approach you have going with the shadow-from-extra-divs, the shadow will eventually bleed out of the edges as you get more and more narrow, so I defined the minimal width at 320px to prevent this. To achieve the exact same effect at even smaller widths without this "shadow bleed", things would get hairy and possibly need a totally other approach. I could be wrong, but I tried to not diverge from the basic idea you had going.

Comment: Mhh okay.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

1- On `nav:before, nav:after` change `top: 80%;` to `top: 35%;`

2- On `nav ul li` if you want the paddings to be applied, change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gWafk/2/

Comment: Thanks... Works a on heights, but if the width decreases to, e.g. 200 it stops showing again (just a little bit left)